# Wrong backline and <0x00> with snakeyaml while saving

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm using [SnakeYAML](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.32).

I save file [here](https://github.com/Elikill58/Negativity/blob/v2/common/src/com/elikill58/negativity/api/yaml/Configuration.java#L349) :

```java
try {
    YamlConfiguration.save(this, file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which is called from [here](https://github.com/Elikill58/Negativity/blob/v2/common/src/com/elikill58/negativity/universal/storage/proof/file/FileNegativityProofStorage.java#L133).

Sometimes, the file get corrupted or have missing content because of content like:

```yaml
my:
  content: "a"
<0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00>
```

Example:

[image]

Or it go back to next line too far:

```yaml
my:
  content:
  - 000000
  - 111111
  - 222222
333
```

Example:

[image]

How can I fix it ? It was appening with other old versions, I updated but it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code having a `ThreadLocal<Yaml>` implies you're writing from multiple threads. You'll need to properly [lock the target file](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lock-files) for that.

This is not guaranteed to be the answer; I see no other obvious flaws in your code though.